# how do i constantly get the mouse location with in a window

Tags: java, canvas, jframe

how do i constantly get the mouse location relative to a window. i don't want to get it only when i click a mouse button. Is there a way to do it with out MouseEvent?

I'm trying to make it where when the mouse is hovering over a spot on the frame a little message box appears giving a description on what it is. My issue is when i move the window to a different location on the screen the position where the message box triggers is still in the same spot relative to the screen and not the window.

Comment: You can use a `MouseMotionListener`.

Comment: thank you so much lol i did not know about mouseMotionListener. it helps alot.

Comment: No problem my good man!